# ActionView::Template::Error: Undefined Method on live server only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This Ruby on Rails problem is a bit vexing, as the code works fine locally but not when I push it onto my live server.

I've added a few int columns into a table using a migration and have a few checkboxes to determine whether items of a certain status are displayed on a certain page, eg:

```
status\page myitems   featureditems   saleitems
status1        X           x             x    
status2        x           x
```

This works fine locally in a development environment, but when I push the code to my live server the "add new feature" page fails to load with the following error:

```
Started GET "/admin/statuses/new" for 86.159.115.236 at 2012-08-19 13:39:12 -0400
Processing by Admin::StatusesController#new as HTML
Rendered shared/_validationerror.html.erb (0.0ms)
Rendered admin/statuses/_form.html.erb (2.1ms)
Rendered admin/statuses/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `show_my_items' for #<Status:0xb6c1690>):
20:       </tr>
21: 
22:       <tr>
23:         <td align="center"><%= f.check_box :show_my_items  %></td>
24:         <td align="center"><%= f.check_box :show_latest_items  %></td>
25:         <td align="center"><%= f.check_box :show_featured_items  %></td>
26:         <td align="center"><%= f.check_box :show_search_results  %></td>
app/views/admin/statuses/_form.html.erb:23:in `block in    
_app_views_admin_statuses__form_html_erb__566719799_79558060'
app/views/admin/statuses/_form.html.erb:1:in   
`_app_views_admin_statuses__form_html_erb__566719799_79558060'
app/views/admin/statuses/new.html.erb:7:in 
`_app_views_admin_statuses_new_html_erb__880262090_94647510'
app/controllers/admin/statuses_controller.rb:31:in `new'
```

In this case 'show_my_items' is one of the fields attached to a status, (represented by page1).

Additionally, on live I can edit a status using the checkbox (but it's int datatype...), but on live, though I can view the edit page and submit without an error, it doesn't actually update the field.

So the columns exist in the database, the code is the same code as I have on live, but the error only happens on the live server. Same version of Rails on both (3.1.0.rc8), ruby versions slightly different (local: 1.9.2p320, live: 1.9.3p194).

No idea what's going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem seems to be that Passenger did not start correctly.  Either it takes longer than I thought or something else went wrong, but having restarted passenger again it worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

Just to be sure, did you run the migration on your server in production mode?

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate
```

Comment: Well...I did initially run it in development mode, and then re-ran in production: `$export RAILS_ENV=production` - so I've checked the code and all _appears_ to be in order, and the columns exist in the db.  It's all very strange.